# What's the meaning of the keyword in of dash javascript declaration

Tags: javascript, macos, documentation

For example, the declaration of getImageData in dash( an app in Mac to provide docsets):

```
ImageData getImageData(   
  in double sx, 
  in double sy, 
  in double sw, 
  in double sh
);
```

What does the in means?

Comment: This is generated doc, for javascript. Also i think its a valid question and hard to find on google when searching for something like "javascript in" one will receive only results for the language keyword.

Comment: Correction its the interface specification by w3c, so not javascript but still reference number one for working against that api. My second point remains valid imho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"in" means its an input variable and not modified by the code, there is also an "out" that marks objects that will be modified i.e.

```
void getImageData(in double sx, in double sy, in double sw, in double sh, out UInt8ClampedArray data);
```

Note: This is not real documentation just an example to illustrate the case.

Comment: Thank you for replying, that's useful for me